# How to create random Actionbar and status bar Oncreate mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

I want to create random `Actionbar` and `Status bar` in `onCreate`, With specified color (orange, green and pink). I found some useful code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    ActionBar actionBar; 
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#879f38")));
```

Comment: do you want to change color each time activity get open or what?

Comment: @SwapnilMeshram yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create array of color in color.xml and pick a random color from it to set the actionbar color as well as status bar color.

```
color.xml

 <array name="actionbar_color">
    <item>@color/bright_pink</item>
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/orange</item>
    <item>@color/yellow</item>
    <item>@color/chartreuse</item>
    <item>@color/green</item>
    <item>@color/spring_green</item>
    <item>@color/cyan</item>
    <item>@color/azure</item>
    <item>@color/blue</item>
    <item>@color/violet</item>
    <item>@color/magenta</item>
</array>
```

In your activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

// further code

int[] actionbarColor = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.actionbar_color);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getRandom(actionbarColor)));
}

public int getRandom(int[] array) {
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
return array[rnd];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, you can also see some experimental code commented out. I use AppCompatActivity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    setupActionBar();
}

    private void setToolbarColor() {
        final int toolbarColor = getResources().getColor(R.id.color_orange);

        // create our manager instance after the content view is set
        final SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
        // enable status bar tint
        tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
        // enable navigation bar tint
        tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);

        // set a custom tint color for all system bars
        tintManager.setTintColor(toolbarColor);

//        // set a custom navigation bar resource
//        tintManager.setNavigationBarTintResource(R.drawable.my_tint);
//        // set a custom status bar drawable
//        tintManager.setStatusBarTintDrawable(MyDrawable);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (null != actionBar) {
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
//            Window.setStatusBarColor();
//            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
//        }
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(toolbarColor));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Random ActionBar Color( According To Current Day )

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void setColor_of_Day() throws ParseException {
    String day=get_Day(get_Date());
    int colorid;
    switch (day){
        case "Sunday":
            colorid=getResources().getColor(R.color.sunday);
            break;

        case "Monday":
            colorid=getResources().getColor(R.color.monday);
            break;

        case "Tuesday":
            colorid=getResources().getColor(R.color.tuesday);
            break;

        case "Wednesday":
            colorid=getResources().getColor(R.color.wednesday);
            break;

        case "Thursday":
            colorid=getResources().getColor(R.color.thursday);
            break;

        case "Friday":
            colorid=getResources().getColor(R.color.friday);
            break;

        case "Saturday":
            colorid=getResources().getColor(R.color.saturday);
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colorid));
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorid);
}

public String get_Day(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dt1=format1.parse(date);
    DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    String day=format2.format(dt1);
    return day;
}


public String get_Date(){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date data= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String date=dateFormat.format(data);
    String formatted_Date=FormatDate(date);
    return formatted_Date;
}
```